# Proving that $f: E\to \mathbb R$, defined by $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-x_0}$ is not uniformly continuous on $E$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, uniform-continuity

Let $E\subset \mathbb R$ and $x_0\notin E$ is a limit point of $E$.

It is to be proven that $f: E\to \mathbb R$, defined by $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-x_0}$ is not uniformly continuous on $E$.

I tried to prove it as follows:

We fix an $\epsilon \gt 0$. Since $x_0$ is a limit point of $E$, for any $\delta\gt 0, \exists y\in E$ such that $|y-x_0|\lt \delta/4$ and $ |y-x_o|\lt \frac{1}{\epsilon+\frac 4{\delta}+|\epsilon-\frac 4{\delta}|} $ 
and

$\exists x\in E$ such that $|x-x_0|\lt \frac{3\delta}4$ and $|x-x_0|\gt \frac{1}{\frac 12(\epsilon+\frac 4\delta)+\frac 12|\epsilon-\frac 4\delta|}\tag{1}$

It follows that $|f(y)|\gt \epsilon+\frac 4{\delta}+|\epsilon-\frac 4{\delta}|$ and $|f(x)|\lt \frac 12(\epsilon+\frac 4{\delta})+\frac 12|\epsilon-\frac 4{\delta}|$

It follows that: $|x-y|\le |x-x_0|+|y-y_0|\lt 3\delta/4+\delta/4=\delta$ and that $|f(y)|-|f(x)|\gt \frac 12(\epsilon+\frac 4{\delta})+\frac 12|\epsilon-\frac 4{\delta}|=\max\{\epsilon, \frac 4\delta\}\gt \epsilon\implies |f(y)-f(x)|\gt \epsilon$.
Since $\delta\gt 0$ is arbitrary, it follows that $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $E$.

Is my proof correct? Thanks.

**Edit:**
In $(1)$: $x$ has  been chosen in such a way that it remains in $(x_0-3\delta/4, x_0+3\delta/4)$, considering that $\max\{\epsilon,\frac 4\delta\}=\frac 12 (\epsilon +\frac 4\delta)+\frac 12|\epsilon -\frac 4\delta|\gt \frac 4\delta\implies \frac 1{\max\{\epsilon,\frac 4\delta\}}\lt \frac \delta 4$.
Now there are two cases: 
**1)** $|x-x_0|\le \frac {\delta }4$ 
In this case, we have: $\frac 1{\max\{\epsilon,\frac 4\delta\}}\lt |x-x_0|\le \frac{ \delta}4\lt \frac {3\delta }4$ 
**2)** $|x-x_0|\gt \frac{\delta }4$. 
In this case, we have $\frac \delta 4\lt |x-x_0|$ and $\frac 1{\max\{\epsilon,\frac 4\delta\}}\lt |x-x_0|\lt \frac{3\delta }4$. 
That is, in both the cases we have $\frac 1{\max\{\epsilon,\frac 4\delta\}}\lt |x-x_0|\lt \frac{3\delta }4$ and this validates our choice of $x$ in $(1)$.

Comment: Can you add more elaboration to $(1)$'s second inequality? And, by the way, as possibly helpful idea: $f$ is unbounded i.e. have no finite limit in $x_0$, so cannot be uniformly continuous.

Comment: @zkutch: Sure. I’ll add it in a moment.

Comment: @zkutch: I have added explanation. I have also taken note of your idea but noting that $x_0\notin E$, will this idea still work?. Particularly here,  I want to show non -uniformity using epsilon delta definition.

Comment: Thanks. Let me say, that in my comment I asked about $(1)$'s second inequality, not first, where $|x-x_0|$ is estimated from below. As to case $x_0 \notin E$, then we have theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$: if $f$ is uniformly continuous on not closed set $E$, then we can continue it continuously on $\overline{E}\setminus E$. And, of course, I see tag solution-verification and your desire to proof it using epsilon/delta. That's why I set question about $(1)$.

Comment: @zkutch: Hi, please let me know if you want more details/clarifications to be added into my post. Is it clarified enough now? I tried to clarify my lower bound only in my edit. Thanks a lot for taking time to review my post :)

Comment: I am asking about $|x-x_0|\gt \frac{1}{\frac 12(\epsilon+\frac 4\delta)+\frac 12|\epsilon-\frac 4\delta|}$.

Comment: @zkutch: Please refer edit and let me know if you want more details/clarifications added to my post. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for patience and work. Maybe it's something wrong with me but why or how obtain you $\frac 1{\max\{\epsilon,\frac 4\delta\}}\lt |x-x_0|$ from $|x-x_0|\le \frac {\delta }4$?

Comment: @zkutch: I have not obtained that. This is how I have chosen my $x$. And such a choice is possible because $x_0$ is a limit point. Why I chose that is because I want to show that for every $\delta \gt 0$, we can have such unruly $x$ and $y$ in $\delta$ neighborhood of $x_0$  for which $|f(y)-f(x)|\gt \epsilon $

Comment: Limit point definition gives estimation from above - I am interested which gives a guarantee of existence of $x$ with a constraint $\frac 1{\max\{\epsilon,\frac 4\delta\}}\lt |x-x_0|$?

Comment: @zkutch: Ahh I see. I had probably taken that unconsciously. But I believe it is right. I may be wrong. Let me think.

Comment: @zkutch: I think that you are right :) If $x_0$ has infinitely many points of $E$ in its say neighborhood of radius 1/8 then still it has infinitely many points in neighborhood of radius 1. Now how do I fix it?

Comment: Thank you for understanding. I think the theorem I gave above should give a way. If you wish, I can reconstruct it schematically in the answer, hoping that this will give a path to your thought.

Comment: @zkutch: Please don't use the theorem you mentioned earlier. Suppose that I currently have only definition of uniform continuity, continuity. That is I would request if you stay as close to $\epsilon -\delta$ definition as possible in your hint/answer.

Comment: @Koro Let me start by saying that I don't think that (1) is true. Even though $x_0$ is not in the set, it's a limit point, so that means there are points close enough to $x_0$  in the set. But I don't see how that implies that there must be a point that is "far enough" from $x_0$ (the sign is $|x-x_0|>...$), given we don't know the size of the set $E$. I'll keep looking. This one could have an answer from me, but I'll look and tell you, of course.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: Madam, you are right. I realized that during my discussion with Mr. zkutch.

Comment: Thanks a lot @zkutch. I realized error in my proof during our discussion. Many thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome @Koro. Glad to be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to solve the more general problem.

Suppose that $E\subset \mathbb{R},\ x_0\notin E$ and $x_0$ is a limit point of $E$. Suppose we are given the function $f:E\to \mathbb{R}$ with the following property: in any deleted neighborhood $f$ is unbounded, i.e. for any $r>0$ the function $f(t)$ is unbounded on $E\cap ((x_0-r,x_0+r)\setminus \{x_0\})$.

One can check that your function $E\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ defined by $t\mapsto \dfrac{1}{t-x_0}$ has this property.

Take any $\delta>0$ consider the neighborhood $W:=E\cap ((x_0-\delta/2,x_0+\delta/2)\setminus \{x_0\})$. Pick a point $x_2\in W$. Since $f$ is unbounded on $W$ then one can find $x_1\in W$ such that $|f(x_1)|>1+|f(x_2)|$.

Therefore, for $\forall \delta>0$ we found $x_1,x_2\in E$ with $|x_1-x_2|<\delta$ but $|f(x_2)-f(x_1)|\geq |f(x_1)|-|f(x_2)|>1.$

Hence $f$ is NOT uniformly continuous on $E$.

$\textit{Remark:}$ The condition that $x_0$ is a limit point of $E$ should be used when we want to prove that $f$ is unbounded in any nbhd of $x_0$.

Comment: Just like that! That's amazing. I understand it.  Thanks a lot :) +1

Comment: @Koro, I am happy that I was able to help you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Koro, Sure! You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x_0\not\in E$ is a limit point of $E$, for any $\epsilon\gt0$, there is an $x_\epsilon\in E$ so that $|x_\epsilon-x_0|\lt\epsilon$.

Now if $f(x)=\frac1{x-x_0}$ were uniformly continuous on $E$, we should be able to find a $\delta\gt0$ so that if $|x-y|\lt\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|\lt1$.

However, for any $\delta\gt0$, by the definition of $x_\epsilon$,
$$
r=|x_{\delta/2}-x_0|\lt\delta/2\tag1
$$
By $(1)$,
$$
|f(x_\delta)|=\frac1r\tag2
$$
Consider the point $x_{r/(r+1)}$. By the definition of $x_\epsilon$ and $(1)$,
$$
\left|x_{r/(r+1)}-x_0\right|\lt\frac{r}{r+1}\lt r\lt\delta/2\tag3
$$
and so
$$
\left|f\!\left(x_{r/(r+1)}\right)\right|\gt1+\frac1r\tag4
$$
By the Triangle inequality and $(1)$ and $(3)$,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|x_{\delta/2}-x_{r/(r+1)}\right|
&\le\overbrace{|x_{\delta/2}-x_0|\vphantom{\left|x_{r/(r+1)}\right|}}^{\lt\delta/2}+\overbrace{\left|x_{r/(r+1)}-x_0\right|}^{\lt\delta/2}\tag{5a}\\[6pt]
&\lt\delta\tag{5b}
\end{align}
$$
However, by the Triangle inequality and $(2)$ and $(4)$,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|f\!\left(x_{r/(r+1)}\right)-f(x_{\delta/2})\right|
&\gt\overbrace{\left|f\!\left(x_{r/(r+1)}\right)\right|}^{\gt1+\frac1r}-\overbrace{\left|f(x_{\delta/2})\right|\vphantom{\left(x_{r/(r+1)}\right)}}^{\frac1r}\tag{6a}\\[6pt]
&\gt1\tag{6b}
\end{align}
$$
Since $\delta\gt0$ was arbitrary, $(5)$ and $(6)$ show that $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. That's exactly what I was trying to do. I was trying to find two unruly points within $\delta $ nbd of $x_0$ to get contradiction. I understand it now from this answer. Instead of $1$, I would fix $\epsilon \gt 0$ and then instead of $x_{(\frac r{r+1 }) }$ I would choose $x_{(\frac r{\epsilon r+1 }) }$ and that would make $|f(x)-f(y)|\gt \epsilon$ thus giving contradiction. This fixes my proof. Many thanks sir :) +1

Comment: If you can't make $f$ closer than $1$, you can't make it closer than an arbitrary $\epsilon$. This is why I chose $1$. That way there is one less variable to pay attention to.

Comment: So for simplification purpose (or so we have one less variable to pay attention to), clever choice $1$ was made. Sir, my understanding of choosing $\epsilon \gt 0$ in my comment is also correct right?

Comment: Yes, if you want to show that the difference is  greater than $\epsilon$, then you'd use $x_{r/(r\epsilon+1)}$. However, since the definition of uniform continuity starts out "for all $\epsilon\gt0$, ..." if we show failure for even one $\epsilon$, we are done.

Comment: :) I see so particularly in this example, we can show for every $\epsilon$. I understand that by negation of uniform continuity definition that we require only one $\epsilon$ for showing failure. Thanks a lot sir :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your proof, but I think it is easier to just use sequences. Since $x_0$ is a limit point of $E$, there is a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\to x_0.$ It is no loss of generality to assume $|x_n-x_0|<1$ for all integers  $n$. Then, with $\epsilon=1,$  if $\delta>0$ is given, there is an integer $N$ such that $|x_N-x_0|<\min\{1,\delta\}$ and then of course $\frac{1}{|x_N-x_0|}>1,$ which contradicts the definition of uniform continuity.

Comment: Thanks. But which part is not clear?  Please let me know.

Comment: I got lost at the first step. I was not able to pick through all the symbols. I think this is a case where it would help if you took for instance $x_0=0$ just for definiteness, and then drew the picture. If you understand what uniform continuity means, then the proof is easy!

Comment: Ahh symbols, I see. I wanted an $\epsilon -\delta $ argument but didn't use sequential criteria. Let me fix up the symbols.

Comment: I had edited my post. I hope it is clearer now.